# Accepting json parameters in my ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an api created with a view model. The request will be in this format:

```
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "type": "TransactionChangedEvent",
  "operationType": "REFUND",
  "operationState": "COMPLETED",
  "created": "2017-05-19T08:27:49.402Z",
  "transaction": {
    "type": "REFUND",
    "id": "345e3802528841bea67dc76744b76ab8",
    "amount": 59.02,
    "currency": "USD",
    "created": "2017-05-19T08:27:49.199Z",
    "updated": "2017-05-19T08:27:49.402Z",
    "state": "COMPLETED",
    "description": "Refund request",
    "maskedPan": "400000...0002",
    "paymentTransactionId": "70eb665c254140558921dfd479a5f390",
    "merchantCustomerId": "cus-123456",
    "customerEmail": "andy@example.com",
    "customerAccountId": "paypal_user_123"
  }
}
```

I'm interested to take data from  `"transaction": {`

My view model class:

```
public virtual string id { get; set; }
public virtual string checkoutUrl { get; set; }
public virtual string state { get;set; }
public virtual decimal? amount { get; set; }
public virtual string currency { get; set; }
public virtual string requestId { get; set; }
public virtual string description { get; set; }
public virtual string paymentInstrument { get; set; }
```

and my controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ProcessDeposit(ViewModel emp)
{
    emp.type = some loginc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what your question is, but your problem is that your view model does not match the format of your json.  If they match, then MVC will magically deserialize everything for you and it will just work.  Based on your JSON sample, you have a child object called transaction, and the rest is just simple properties, so your model needs to look like this:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string operationType { get; set; }
    public string operationState { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public Transaction transaction { get; set; } // child object
}
```

and you need to define a transaction class to handle the child object:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    // ... add remaining properties of Transaction here
}
```

Then make your `ViewModel` a `TransactionViewModel`, and it should work.  If you need to change it to a different format to render a view or something, you can do that conversion inside the controller action.